# I want the same height in both container. If the left content increase I want to increase the height in both side

Tags: flutter, dart

i want same equal size in both container. Anyone help me to set the both  container is equal height when the anyone content is increase

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 7,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Day ${index + 1}',
                style:
                    clientStyle(fontSize: xLSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              subtitle: IntrinsicHeight(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: fitishBlue.withOpacity(0.15),
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Potato: 0g  Rice: 0g Beans: 0g Milk: 0g Yogurt: 0g Cheese: 0g Cheese: 0g Cheese: 0g',
                          style: clientStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: fitishBlue.withOpacity(0.4),
                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Protein: 0g \nCarbs: 0g \nFats: 0g',
                          style: clientStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        )
```

I get...
[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngbrV.png)

i want..with the content missing
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVvdK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are already limiting the height of the row widget because you have "wrapped" it with an `IntrinsicHeight`, which is a good start.

You just need you set `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` in the row constructor.

As indicated in its `CrossAxisAlignment` docs:

> Require the children to fill the cross axis.
>
> This causes the
> constraints passed to the children to be tight in the cross axis.
> `stretch`

Comment: @mohamed-rifay did this solve your problem? If yes please mark the answer as the accepted solution or provide more information on how to help you.